# Rigging in pose mode generates waves

Tags: animation, rigging

I have done my rig and assigned it with automatic weights, it all seems fine until I try to move it in pose mode and it generates this wavy kind of look. How can I fix this? :(

[image]

Comment: Are you using the remesh or subdivision surface modifiers?

Comment: yes, i have subdiv modifier